# How to rename many variable names at once (C/C++)

Tags: c

Is there a tool that will allow me to rename a large number of variable names at once?

I have a large number of variables that I want to put into a C structure and therefore, I would need to add a parameter to the beginning of each name included in the structure.

Comment: Check find/replace(all), every decent (text)editor has it. :)

Comment: That will only allow me to change one variable at a time, which would take a long time.

Comment: not at all, any descent editor (vim) can do block-replace etc using a regexp which allows you to specify the variable-names without actually specifying them. What environment do you have?

Comment: I am using Code Composer Studio 5.3 (eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it at once, put a regular expression into your advanced search/replace function. ^(name1|name2|name3)$ ought to work. But no guarantee that it won't catch other things besides variable uses (in particular, the variable declarations). If you want that, you would have to work with something like Clang's tooling.

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html - of course that is a major effort, since it requires writing a program specifially for your use case.

Comment: It didn't work when tried using only two variable names, i.e. ^(var1|var2)$.  It didn't find either variable name.  I selected regular expressions in the find/replace dialog box in Code Composer Studio 5.3 (eclipse).

Comment: Ok. When I said it worked, I ment I was able to find the variables.  However, replacing the variables is another story.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` with `find`, in a shell terminal, as in:

```
$ find /path/to/project/root -name "*.[ch]" -exec sed -ri 's/original_name/new_name/' {} \;
```

Comment: note that `s/car/cat/` will turn `carpet` into `catpet` so beware!

Comment: Is there a sed for windows?

Comment: have a look at www.cygwin.com

Comment: Fredrik Pihl:  Thanks. My variables are very descriptive and long, so I don't think I will have a problem with that issue.  Consequently, if it does happen, I think it will only happen to a very few of my variables.  Why did someone give -1 to this suggestion?

Comment: where to write this command? what is required to run it?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any tool that will allow me to rename a large number of variable names at once.

Every half-decent IDE has a feature for this. You said that you're using Eclipse, so you can select the variable that you want to rename and then use the [Refactor command](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_rename.htm) to change the name in all your files.